# Common idioms/euphemisms for "satisfy"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, euphemisms

I've checked a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/satisfy) but I've never heard of the idioms/euphemisms listed there. Are they common? If not, what are better options?

Example sentence:

> Mary's husband wasn't satisfying her.

Comment: In your reference to euphemisms, do you mean to say that *Mary's husband wasn't satisfying her sexually*? Or do you mean a more general satisfaction?

Comment: He (or his performance, or his honesty, or...) *left something to be desired*.

Comment: Is he neglecting her?  (a frequency problem)  Or is he not being responsive to her needs?  (a qualitative problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider ***meet (someone's) expectations***. It sounds milder that *not satisfying* and should qualify as a *euphemism*.

> Mary's husband wasn't ***meeting her expectations***.

TFD:

> **[meet (someone's) expectations](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meet+(someone's)+expectations)**
>   To be as good as or have the qualities that someone predicted, expected, or hoped for.
>
> We'd heard
>   so many good things about the new restaurant, but the food didn't meet
>   our expectations at all.
>   I'm so excited for the latest movie in the
>   series—I hope it meets my expectations!

Comment: Context is everything here and the OP's quote is more often than not referenced to the intimate aspect of a conjugal relationship. My comment can't get more euphemistic than that, what?

Comment: @PeterPoint, I disagree. My answer's validity is independent of context. The downvoter's right to have their own opinion is acknowledged. I hope my response is euphemistic enough! :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Most satisfying; it met my expectations to the full! :)